# How to save plot along with legends as an image?

Tags: plotting

When i want to save the output ,which includes a plotlegends option in it,  i can not save the output graph or in other words, the mathematica does not offer the suggestions bar!
For example

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 0.2}, PlotLegends->"sin"]
```

Can anybody help me.

Thanks

Comment: `i can not save the output graph`  This is not clear.  Try to add more words to describe the problem. Do you want to `Export` the plot?

Comment: Yes. I want export as, say png. But suggestions bar does not offer options for extract

Comment: To export, just do `p=Plot[....]` and then just do `Export["foo.png",p]`  You might first want to do `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]`, so the the file "foo.png" gets saved in same folder as notebook so easy to find. This is what I do for all my HWs. But I suggest you save to PDF and not PNG. PDF  is vector graphics. Works for any resolution.

Comment: @PhysicsExams What you mean by suggestion bar?

Comment: @MMM http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframPredictiveInterface.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you meant to say that the legend line is not showing then you need `PlotLegends ->{}`,

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 0.2}, PlotLegends -> {"sin"}]
```

[image]

**Legends inside the plot frame**

But if you want to save the image along with the legends then, bring the legend inside the frame, then you will be able to save the plot and legend in the same image,

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"sin"}, LegendFunction -> Frame, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {{55, 10}}], {0.8, 0.2}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**`Rasterize`**

You can avoid using `Export` to save image along with the legends by using `Rasterize`

```
Rasterize[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 0.2}, PlotLegends -> {"sin"}]]
```

[image]

**`Export`**

As suggested by @Nasser, `Export` will directly save the image with any extension along with legends.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 0.2}, PlotLegends -> {"sin"}];
Export["C:/tcdata/myimage.png", %]
```

Comment: `But if you want to save the image along with the legends then, bring the legend inside the frame` Actually, the `Export` command will save the plot along with the legend without having to put the legend inside the frame. That is why the question is not clear what the problem is. But +1 for showing how to put the legend inside. This can be useful sometimes

Comment: @Nasser I never tried exporting an image. For my personal plotting, I use `Tecplot`. But thanks, now I know about it (plot with legend saving).